# Programmatically load e4 Application Model

Tags: e4

I am trying to programmatically load an e4 application model in order to be able to iterate on the model elements. Currently I am facing the problem, that I don't know on how to correctly load it.

Given an `Application.e4xmi` I tried to simply load the file using simple [load an existing model](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMFPersistence/article.html#javacode_load) which however did not result in a populated Resource (null).

Then I found out about `org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui.common.XMIModelResource`, I am however not able to instantiate the model using the following code

```
URI uriNew = URI.createURI("file:///Users/marco/github-clones/osara/at.osara.rcp/Application.e4xmi");
XMIModelResource xmimr = new XMIModelResource(uriNew);
```

as I get `Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application' not found.` This ecore however is located in the already imported `org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench`

Anybody got a hint on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is quite simple; the respective EMF model is not yet registered in the workspace. In order to do so, the following code has to be executed before loading the model:

```
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationPackageImpl;
ApplicationPackageImpl.init();
```

Here goes a full code sample for loading an Eclipse 4 Application model in a standalone main method:

```
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4XMIResourceFactory;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationPackageImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;

public class LoadAppModel {

    private static ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationPackageImpl.init();
        URI uri = URI
                .createURI("file:///Users/marco/git/pharmacy_at/at.medevit.ecrit.pharmacy_at.application/Application.e4xmi");

        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap()
                .put("e4xmi", new E4XMIResourceFactory());

        Resource res = resourceSet.getResource(uri, true);
        MApplication app = (MApplication) res.getContents().get(0);
        System.out.println(app.getElementId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the injected `EModelService` or `MApplication` classes.
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/12/01/e4-emodelservice/) is more info.

Comment: I'm sorry, thats not the problem! In your info one loads the application model of an already available application! I am trying to load the application model out of a file without using it!

Comment: Weird, i've get the following:
URI uriNew = URI.createURI("file:///Users/kirill/Documents/Dev/DW/DomainWorkbench/org.domainworkbench/Application.e4xmi");  XMIModelResource xmimr = new XMIModelResource(uriNew);  assertNotNull(xmimr);
assertEquals(1, xmimr.getRoot().size());
Dependencies:
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.junit,
 org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui;bundle-version="0.12.0",
 org.eclipse.platform;bundle-version="4.3.0",
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable;bundle-version="1.4.1"
green...

Comment: And for org.eclipse.platform;bundle-version="4.2.1" it also works. (of course against the model without DynamicMenuContributions...).